# LWC : Map Marker - map component not getting refreshed Once the value is updated in the field

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

JS :

```
import { LightningElement,api,track,wire } from 'lwc';

import retriveLatLon  from '@salesforce/apex/mapComponentLWCController.retriveLatLon';

export default class MapComponentLWC extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    @api LatField;
    @api LonField;
    @track mapMarkers;
    @track zoomLevel = 15;

    @wire(retriveLatLon,{recID : '$recordId', Lat_ApiName :'$LatField',Log_ApiName :'$LonField' })
    getValues({error,data}){

        if(data){
            var obj = JSON.parse(data);
            var Lon = obj.lon_Val;
            var Lat = obj.lat_Val;            
            this.mapMarkers = [{
                location: {
                    Latitude: Lat,
                    Longitude: Lon
                }
            }];
            
        }
        else if(error){
            console.log('-----error-----' + error.body.message);
            
        } 
    }    
}
```

Apex controller :

```
public class mapComponentLWCController {
    
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static String retriveLatLon(Id recID,String Lat_ApiName,String Log_ApiName){
        //id recID = 'a0G0p000001aps7EAA';
        String objectName = recID.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName();
        String condition = 'id =:recID';
        String QUERY_STRING = 'SELECT id, {0},{1} FROM {2} WHERE {3}';
        List<String> queryParamList = new List<String>();
        queryParamList.add(Lat_ApiName);
        queryParamList.add(Log_ApiName);
        queryParamList.add(objectName);
        queryParamList.add(condition);       
        String soqlQuery = String.format(QUERY_STRING, queryParamList);
        List<sObject> resultQuery = Database.query(soqlQuery);
        //system.debug('Query '+resultQuery);
        SObject result;
        if(!resultQuery.isEmpty()){
            result = resultQuery.get(0);
        }
        
        wrap_Class value =new wrap_Class();
        value.Lat_Val = String.valueOf(result.get(Lat_ApiName));
        value.Lon_Val = String.valueOf(result.get(Log_ApiName));
         system.debug('Query '+value);
        return Json.serialize(value);
       
    }
    
    public Class wrap_Class{
        String lat_Val;
        String lon_Val;
        
    }

}
```

HTML :

```
<template>
    <lightning-map
        map-markers={mapMarkers}
        zoom-level={zoomLevel}>
    </lightning-map>
</template>
```

Meta XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>50.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
               
    </targets>
     
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__AppPage, lightning__HomePage,lightning__RecordPage">
            <property name="LatField" type="String" label="Lattitude Field" description="Provide the Lattitude Field API name"/>
             <property name="LonField" type="String" label="Longitude Field" description="Provide the Longitude Field API name"/>
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
    </LightningComponentBundle>
```

Answer (score 0):

[LWC documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.data_ui_api) states the following:

> Lightning Data Service manages data for you; changes to a record are
> reflected in all the technologies built on it. Contrastingly, data
> from Apex is not managed; you must refresh the data.

You are using a wired custom apex call and a change in the field data (*on the server*) will not be automatically notified to the component; so your component doesn't know that the field values have changed. The data fetched by the lightning web component is stored in the browser cache, with its cache duration automatically defined by the platform. You need to write (*may be lot of*) code to detect field value changes on the server and notify the component to refresh the stale cached data (*using `refreshApex()` from `@salesforce/apex`*). Check [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/apex_result_caching) out.

For detecting the change in the field value and notifying the component, you will need to write a service layer & server side API (*similar to Lightning Data Service & User Interface API*) which will not be a simple answer or there could be a medium complex alternative approach; both of which depend on your business needs and is beyond the scope of this question.